# Getting incomplete response from GitHub API

Tags: node.js, github-api

I'm trying to learn nodejs and have this page which is supposed to print out all of the repos that someone has at GitHub. Right now, it randomly stops halfway through the message, so if I try to parse it into JSON it fails.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  var https = require('https');
  var options = {
    host: 'api.github.com',
    headers: {'user-agent': 'GitHubAPI'},
    path: '/users/vermiculus/repos'
  };
  var gitapi = https.get(options, function(git) {
    git.on("data", function(chunk) {
      //JSON.parse(chunk); //DEBUG Fails and dies.
      res.end(chunk);
    });
  });
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Edit: Here's a sample response. See how it literally stops in the middle of a string.

```
[{"id":24659454,"name":"arara","full_name":"vermiculus/arara","owner":{"login":"vermiculus","id":2082195,"avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/2082195?v=3","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/vermiculus","html_url":"https://github.c
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` event for the response object of `https.get()` can get called multiple times, but you're ending your HTTP server's response after the first.

You should collect all the chunks and combine them in an `end` handler:

```
var gitapi = https.get(options, function(git) {
  var chunks = [];

  git.on("data", function(chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  git.on("end", function() {
    var json = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    res.end(json);
  });
});
```

FWIW, if the GH API data is JSON, setting `text/plain` as content type doesn't make a lot of sense.

If you just want to proxy the GH responses, you can also use `pipe()` (which basically does the same as above, just more efficiently):

```
var gitapi = https.get(options, function(git) {
  git.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: It's a little surprising to me that this is not done a little more 'automatically' in the vein of an XMLHTTPRequest where you can at least set a callback and have the response ready somewhere without having to manually concatenate chunks.

Comment: @kzahel I agree it's a bit low level, but it also allows for stream processing (or piping) that won't require the entire response to be read into memory first. To make things easier, there are various modules (like [`stream-collect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-collect) or [`collect-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/collect-stream)) to hide the internals.

Comment: @robertklep: This is probably just Haskell corrupting me, but why doesn't `git.on("data", chunks.push);` work as an alternative to creating an anonymous function?

Comment: @JoshuaSnider you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) the function to the `chunks` array: `response.on('data', chunks.push.bind(chunks))`

Answer (score 1):

You're using `res.end` after you get a chunk of data. Try to concatenate all the chunks into one single string before parsing it.

```
var gitapi = https.get(options, function(git) {
var body = '';
git.on("data", function(chunk) {
  body += chunk.toString('utf8');
});
git.on("end", function() {
   //var json = JSON.parse(body)
   res.end(body);
});
});
```